# Sync Databases on two computers

Tags: sql-server, database

This is kind of common scenario. I have 2 laptops(my wife's and mine) at home. I have SQL Server 2008 on both the machines. The databases get out of sync with each other.

I am trying to create a small application which will help me manage my bank and credit cards passwords. If either my wife or I change any of the accounts passwords, we update the Database. But this is causing headaches as the database on my machine gets out of sync with that of my wife's machine.

What options do I have to keep the databases in sync? Will [Windows Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=winxp) be of any aid? I am bit skeptical as I don't want to share my db files containing passwords on a public site.

Comment: Mirroring or Replication might be able to do what you want.. But it seems like they both would prefer only one database to be the primary source for the changes (I am not sure you could mirror to a mirror for example, almost sounds like it would infinite loop) Here is the link to microsoft's article on the topics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be overkill for such a simple scenario, but this sounds like a case for [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is something called as change-tracking in-built in 2008 edition, using which you can setup synchronization (using Sync framework).

You can use this

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BCE4AD61-5B76-4101-8311-E928E7250B9A&displaylang=en

this can help you setup sync either directly or using an intermediate Sql azure db (basically sql server on the cloud).

Answer (score 0):

I just got through trying almost the exact same thing with Live Mesh, only to find out that there are certain file types that won't sync: http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-sync-file-types-ui

I'm assuming at .mdf and .ldf are considered system files, because Live Mesh would not sync them.

**EDIT**: Apparently I'm just too impatient. The .mdf and the .ldf files both ended up syncing.  It just took a while for some reason.